# Google fonts not showing up on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, heroku

So I have been following a ruby on rails tutorial.  When I load my app onto heroku, the google font that I chose (Lato) does not show up on my computer when using chrome.

It shows up on other web browsers and on others' computers who are using chrome

I have changed the http: to https:, I have done all of the other searches required but am still having difficulty figuring it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing http and https, so it starts with // 
from this:    http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato
to this:    //fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato

Comment: So I was able to figure it out.  I am a bit of a newbie to this so understand that the resolution to this was a bit of a rookie mistake.  At first, I did add the https: to the web address as well as removing the http altogether.  My problem was that I failed to do the git add ., and the git commit commands before pushing it all to heroku.  I did it and now it all works just fine.  Like I said, a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your browser cache/cookies. If it shows up correctly on other computers it's likely related to your computer/browser

Answer (score 0):

If its working on other systems but not yours then dump your Cached Images and Files to the Beginning of Time.

For chrome.

#### ⌘-Shift-Delete